# How to Get the Last Day of the Previous Month?

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

Is there a quicker and easier to read way in order to get the last day of the previous month in T-SQL?

I have found this piece of source code, which does the trick, but looks obfuscated unless properly previously commented:

```
-- Declar variabila pentru ultima zi din luna anterioară.
DECLARE @DSL [DATETIME]
SET @DSL = (SELECT DATEADD(  dd
                           ,  0
                           , DATEDIFF(  dd
                                      ,  0
                                      , DATEADD(   s
                                                , -1
                                                , DATEADD(  mm
                                                          , DATEDIFF(  m
                                                                     , 0
                                                                     , GETDATE())
                                                          , 0)))))
PRINT 'Declar variabila pentru ultima zi din luna anterioară.'
PRINT @DSL
```

The message window with the results show the following output:

```
Declar variabila pentru ultima zi din luna anterioară.
Mar 31 2015 12:00AM
```

Please forgive my ignorance, I feel like a new-born newbie when I see these tricks.

`SELECT @@VERSION` reports:

> Microsoft SQL Server 2008 (SP2) - 10.0.4000.0 (Intel X86) 
>       Sep 16 2010 20:09:22 
>       Copyright (c) 1988-2008 Microsoft Corporation
>       Express Edition with Advanced Services on Windows NT 5.1  (Build 2600: Service Pack 3)

Comment: You should definitely look into building a calendar/dates table if you do a lot of work with dates.

Comment: Right. I have noticed that there are some stored procedures called such as `[ReportServer$Company].[dbo].[GetMondayDate] ( GETDATE() )` obviously meant to get the date of the most recent Monday. Probably once there has been a trend to simplify things, yet I still find loads of blocks of source code that look daunting and obfuscated, produced by speedy uncommented copy-paste operations.

Comment: Hmm...I was thinking something along the lines of this http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/22776.t-sql-calendar-table.aspx but also adding in any extra fields  (like Last_Day_Previous_Month) that you may need. Something like that would potentially be better than `DATEADD` functions as you could then do `SELECT Last_Day_Previous_Month FROM dbo.calendar AS c WHERE c.date = CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)` and utilise the table in joins

Comment: I see. Thank you for commenting. So this is how things are done. I will try to start changing things when I get some spare time. The whole code looks like spaghetti code to me. Still, my T-SQL knowledge is very, very limited, as I come from the C/C++ area where I like to keep things really short. I shall read the article soon. Thanks for posting its link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This one works in SQL Server 2008 R2, will probably work on SQL Server 2008 too :

```
DECLARE @DSL [DATETIME]
SET @DSL = (SELECT DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, -1, GETDATE())-1, -1))
PRINT 'Declar variabila pentru ultima zi din luna anterioară.'
PRINT @DSL
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @dtCurrentDate DATETIME = GETDATE()
print @dtCurrentDate
SELECT DATEADD(DAY, 
            -1, 
            DATEADD(MONTH,DATEDIFF(MONTH,0,@dtCurrentDate),0))
,DATEADD(DAY
            ,-DAY(@dtCurrentDate)
            ,DATEADD(DAY,DATEDIFF(DAY,0,@dtCurrentDate),0))
```

Comment: Very good answer, too. I have just chosen @DeadEye's for brevity. I hope the moderators won't disqualify me for subjectivity.

Comment: No prob; Bafta!